# "Referenced by" or "reference for"

Tags: word-choice

Context: we are Team A of a company, we aim to make a product PA. There is a Team B in the company, they have created a product PB. The product PA and the product PB have some similarities. So the experience of Team B making PB can be useful for us to make PA from time to time. We will ask Team B's advices when we are stuck in some specific issues that we know that they know.

On the one hand, it is good to let outside know that Team A and Team B are from the same company, and we have Team B's support when necessary. On the other hand, we cannot highlight Team B too much, because it's our team that is supposed to build PA and to know how to do it.

So, is it correct to say (to outside)

- "Team B's experience in building PB can be referenced by us."
- "Team B's experience in building PB can be a reference for us."
- is there any other better way to say that?

Comment: You can use Team B as a *model*.

Comment: `model` sounds a little bit too strong. I don't want to stress the importance of Team B that much, because it's our team that is supposed to build PA and to know how to do that.

Comment: That may be what you're supposed to do, but you stated that you're making use of their experience, so you're not actually doing it on your own.

Comment: We may ask them their advises and opinions when we are really stuck in some issues that we know that they know, that's quite it. (but it is already a privilege, because other companies would not have this access to Team B).

Comment: "Team B can be consulted in an emergency"

Comment: "Team B can be consulted in an emergency" ==> It sounds that Team B is stronger than us in this subject, we don't want to give people this impression.

Comment: All your arguments seem to deny the reality of the situation you described. Why do you need to say anything if you don't want to give these impressions?

Comment: It is good to let outside know that we have kind of support of Team B when necessary. And it is important to let outside know that Team A has the main resource to create PA.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to say it without suggesting that you may need this reference.

Comment: You will consult with Team B and take advantage of their skills and experience.

Comment: Team B isn't a ***reference*** for Team A. They're a ***resource***.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to not overemphasise Team B, at the same time want to acknowledge them. You can use words such as "auxiliary"/"subordinate"/"associative"/"supplementary"/"secondary". e.g.

```
Team B helps us with auxiliary support.
Team B provides us with an auxiliary role.
Team B provides us with supplementary assistance.
```

There are other words such as "harmony" or "enhance"

```
Team B acts in harmony with us.
Team B enhances us in their supportive role.
```